# Using stroke_bounds in an extension method colors all horizontal_line and vertical_line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have a method in a module that's added to the extensions that looks something like this

```
def competence(title, has, needs, color = '000000')
  bounding_box [0, cursor], width: 280, height: 15 do
    stroke_color color
    stroke_bounds
    stroke_color '000000'
    text title, size: 12, align: :right, valign: :center
  end
  draw_text has, at: [295, cursor], size: 8
  draw_text needs, at: [335, cursor], size: 8
end
```

When I then use this method in my document, it changes the color of all previous `horizontal_line` and `vertical_line` on the same page to the `stroke_color` in the method. It only colors it the first time, so using the method again does not change the colors again.

I figure out a shitty fix by just creating a method that makes a tiny offscreen box with black bounds, but having to do this is kind of stupid.

Is this a bug, am I missing something, using something wrong or is there a better fix for this?

edit: the same happens to elipses and circles with fill_color